# Examine RSpec examples without running them

Tags: rspec, continuous-integration

My spec_helper has the standard:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.filter_run focus: true
  config.run_all_when_everything_filtered = true
end
```

That's great for while I'm working on something, but I want my CI build to fail if I accidentally commit a focused spec.

Any ideas?

Comment: What about only adding `config.filter_run focus: true` in development, for instance by checking if an ENV variable exist?

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much what Myron said here: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/issues/1747

Comment: You should post the answer and accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the advice [Myron provided](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/issues/1747#issuecomment-60314023). It has been working out great for me.

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  if ENV['CI']
    config.before(:example, :focus) { raise "Should not commit focused specs" }
  else
    config.filter_run focus: true
    config.run_all_when_everything_filtered = true
  end
end
```